# Add a proactive counter in SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, hive

I have a table like this:

```
Row#    ID    Indicator
 1      001      Yes
 2      001      No
 3      001      No
 4      001      No
 5      001      No
 6      001      Yes
 7      001      No
 8      002      No
 9      002      No
 10     002      No
 11     002      No
 12     002      No
 13     002      No
 14     002      Yes
 15     002      No
 16     003      No
 17     003      Yes
 18     003      No
 19     003      No
 20     003      No
 21     003      No
 22     004      No
 .        .      .
 .        .      .
100     020      Yes
```

I want to have a counter that count number of every 3 consecutive 'No' and group by ID.  The counter function triggers when it sees a "No". Once 3 consecutive rows of "No" occur, counter = counter + 1. No double count is allowed.

For instance:
For ID = 001, there are three consecutive "No" from row 2 to row 4, so counter value = 1.

Since "No" from row 2 to row 4 have been used, row 3 to row 5 can't be counted as an event because of 
no double count rule.

For ID = 002, there are three consecutive "No" from row 8 to row 10 and 
from row 11 to row 13, so counter value = 2.

The desired output would be like this:

```
ID    Counter
001      1
002      2
003      1
 .       .
 .       .
100      0
```

Edit 1: row # is not a real column. it's for explanation purpose.
Edit 2: I realized row# is essential to this problem. Let's make it a real column again. so the original data sample given above remain valid.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Which database server are you using? DB2?

Comment: I'm using oracle database server.

Comment: Your example table has a `Row#` column. Is this a real column in the table, or is it there to make the question explanation easier?

Comment: @ohmyan: it's a good idea to use the [tag:oracle] tag for Oracle questions so that you don't get MySql answers.

Comment: So, id 2000 has _no no yes no no_. That is a count of zero, because they were not consecutive, correct? If the count is 1, then group by ID, where no, count(*)/3.

Comment: If you use Oracle, that what about the `hive` tag?

Comment: Hmm ... If Row# is only for explanation then you can't get correct answer at all because there are no original sequence to follow.  I.e. suppose we have `ID=777` and there are 2 `Yes` and 4 `No` which may appear in select in any order randomly: `YYNNNN'`or `YNNYNN` or any other variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive supports `row_number()`, so you can use that to enumerate the values.  The logic may not be obvious at first, but the idea is to enumerate consecutive "N" values and divide the result by 3.  This latter piece is the logic for getting the number of sequences that you want.

The following version works assuming that there is only one long sequence of "N"s.  This is the format of the data in the question:

```
select t.id, max(floor(seqnum / 3.0))
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, indicator, grp order by row#) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   (row_number() over (partition by id order by row#) -
                    row_number() over (partition by id, indicator order by row#)
                   ) as grp
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t
where indicator = 'N'
group by id;
```

This can be modified to handle multiple sequences of "N"s for a given id, but the query is a little bit more complicated.

EDIT:

I realize that the following is more general:

```
select t.id, sum(case when pmod(seqnum, 3) = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: @ohmyan . . . Then you have a misformed question.  You are asking about sequential values in a relational table without providing a column to indicate the ordering.  SQL tables represent unordered sets, so you need a columns to contain ordering information.